# Cassandra's sstableloader too slow in import data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using the command line `sstableloader` to replication datas in the cassandra version 3.11. The process's duration is the 3 hours and 8 minutes to process the amount 356kb. Does this duration is normal independent the amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sstableload should not take much longer. but you may be throttle your data transfer by default

> --throttle 1

(units in MBs). You can speed it up by controlling number of connection per host.

> sstableloader --node node_ip --connection-per-host 100

Another reason is if you're using the default and seems very slow. maybe the sstable files loaded compacted while reading them. you need to place your loaded files in directory far from the Cassandra data directory.