# cassandra Backup from one node to another node

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, gremlin-server

I'm new to cassandra and gremlin.i am using gremlin to enter and retrive the data from cassandra .i want to take a bakup and restore it on new node.i took a snapshot using nodetool.i am also using elasticsearch for indexing.please help me with some links or documents

Comment: Hi Syed, I hope this link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639544/how-do-i-replicate-a-cassandras-local-node-for-other-cassandras-remote-node

Comment: I have the steps, if you need it, let me know.

Comment: yeah i  need the steps.it would be great help to me

Comment: I shared with you the process I do. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I used the secound approach of this post : [How do I replicate a Cassandra's local node for other Cassandra's remote node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639544/how-do-i-replicate-a-cassandras-local-node-for-other-cassandras-remote-node)

If structure of the tables is the same, you could create two bash's scripts like below:

**1. Export the data using these commands:**

```
nodetool flush <your-keyspace-name>
nodetool cleanup <your-keyspace-name>
nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 snapshot <your-keyspace-name>
zip -r /tmp/bkp.zip /var/lib/cassandra/data/<your-keyspace-name>/
sshpass -p <password> scp -v /tmp/bkp.zip root@<ip>:/tmp
```

**2. Import the data:**

```
unzip /tmp/bkp.zip
nodetool cleanup <your-keyspace-name>
cd /var/lib/cassandra/data/<your-keyspace-name>/ && find /var/lib/cassandra/data/<your-keyspace-name>/ -maxdepth 5 -type d -exec sstableloader -v --nodes 127.0.0.1 {} \;
```

If you note some slow process, please check this another post: [Cassandra's sstableloader too slow in import data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297579/cassandras-sstableloader-too-slow-in-import-data)

**Important: You should adapt this informaction to your reallity.**

Answer (score 0):

i followed the below steps and the restoration worked

**for backup**

go to the path cd /var/lib/cassandra/data

then take the snapshot using the command below

**nodetool snapshot janusgraph -cf edgestore -t edgestore_mar6**

**nodetool snapshot janusgraph -cf graphindex -t graphindex_mar6**

i took the backup of all the folders present in the directory janusgraph under  /var/lib/cassandra/data

now move to the folder **cd /var/lib/cassandra/data/janusgraph** and type give the command **ls -lrth**.

the latest folders will be present at the bottom then go to those folders and go inside the snapshot folders present inside those folders.

eg

**cd /var/lib/cassandra/data/janusgraph/graphindex-8e147200236f11edbecf211c2dd12670/snapshots**

and copied that graphindex_mar6 to a new diretory

i repeated it for all the others folders under keyspace(directory) janusgraph,copied all the folders with today's date to a new directory and using the tar command i compressed the new directory

**tar cvzf janusgraph_mar6.tar.gz janusgraph**

here janusgraph is the directory i created and copied all the snapshots of all the  folders under keyspace(directory) janusgraph.

**for restoring**

then copy the  janusgraph_mar6.tar.gz folder to the remote machine,where we want to restore the data

uncompress the janusgraph folder

**tar xvzf janusgraph_mar6.tar.gz**

then under the folder janusgraph ,rename the other folders

eg  edgestore_mar6  to edgestore

mv  edgestore_mar6   edgestore

graphindex_mar6 to graphindex

mv graphindex_mar6  graphindex

repeat for all the folders

then restore using the command

**sstableloader -d cassandra-ip /home/ubuntu/janusgraph/graphindex/**

**sstableloader -d cassandra-ip /home/ubuntu/janusgraph/edgestore/**

here we can get the cassandra-ip by running the command **nodetool status**,use the above commands for all the other folders and then restart cassandra

**sudo service restart cassandra**

my data was restored

since i used elasticsearch for indexing in my backend ,i ran the my reindexing script on gremlin console after restoration

Comment: if we use docker container exeute the commands inside the container